# Split up Arduino code into multiple files using Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino

I am working on a very long code that requires multiple functions defined.

I want to split the code into two files as main code ("Feeder_Control" in the screenshot) and functions ("connections" in the screenshot).

How to import the second file into main code to use its functions?

PS: In C/C++ same thing is done with `#include "connections.h"`. How is it done in Arduino IDE.

[image]

Comment: You can create multiple tabs in the Arduino IDE to split up your code into separate files.

Comment: You may want to add this question to https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: have you tried #include "pathfoldername/connections.ino"  ?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new tab in the IDE, you must set the file extension to either `*.h`/`*.c`/`*.cpp`. This will then tell the compiler what file you are referencing, otherwise you could be referencing anything. At the moment, `connections` doesn't have an extension, so the compile won't be able to understand your reference `#include "connections.ino"`.

So, create a new file, and call it "Connections.h" (without quotes). Then in your main code, you can include using `#include "Connections.h"`.